Polygons Importing in QGIS from a CSV file
I have a CSV file which has coordinates for polygons. I want to import these polygons into QGIS. sample data is given as:
ID  X1      Y1      X2      Y2       X3     Y3       X4     Y4
1   3835    144    3835     157     3756    155     3756    143
2   2527    1450    2538    1457    2488    1543    2477    1536
3   2618    1631    2631    1640    2564    1732    2552    1723

I tried all the way I could but could not import the polygons.
Is there a video tutorial or detailed explanation (article) available?
I want to import these polygons over a raster layer.
I followed the below steps but it couldn't help:

Load the TIFF Image:
Make sure the TIFF image is already loaded into QGIS as a raster layer. If not, you can do so by dragging and dropping the TIFF file into the QGIS window or by using the "Layer" > "Add Layer" > "Add Raster Layer" option.

Add the CSV File as a Vector Layer:
Go to the "Layer" menu.
Select "Add Layer" > "Add Delimited Text Layer".
Browse and select the CSV file containing the polygons.
Ensure the X and Y coordinate fields are correctly specified.
Choose the appropriate CRS for your data.
Click "Add" to add the CSV file as a new vector layer in QGIS.

Adjust Styling and Symbolization:
Once the vector layer is added, you may need to adjust the styling and symbolization to make the polygons visible on the map canvas.
Open the Layer Styling panel for the vector layer by right-clicking on the layer in the Layers panel and selecting "Properties".
In the "Symbology" tab, choose a suitable style and color for the polygons.

Adjust Layer Order:
Ensure that the vector layer containing the polygons is positioned above the raster layer (TIFF image) in the Layers panel. You can drag and drop the layers to rearrange their order.



Welcome  to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a problem-solving site, not a tutorial reference service. In order to get assistance, you need to tell us what you have done, and what problem you encountered. It seems highly likely that the object coordinates are relative to the pixel locations in the image, so you have some math to do, relative to the corner coordinates of the image.

Which step are you stuck on?

Restructure (unpivot) your csv to the columns ID, X, Y and add rows for each coordinate column. (You can use pandas.melt for this if you have a large dataset)
ID,X,Y
1,3835,144
1,3835,157
1,3756,155
1,3756,143
2,2527,1450
2,2538,1457
2,2488,1543
2,2477,1536
3,2618,1631
3,2631,1640
3,2564,1732
3,2552,1723

Add as delimited text layer (Change the crs to the correct one):

If all your polygons are convex, Minimum bounding geometry should work to create polygons of each ID point set:


You could create a WKT string within excel using:
="POLYGON (("&B2&" "&C2&", "&D2&" "&E2&", "&F2&" "&G2&", "&H2&" "&I2&"))"


Then add the CSV as delimited text layer using WKT as geometry definition:

